Using SwiftUI's ScrollView with rotation in
I am developing a chat app.
If I don't rotate SwiftUI's ScrollView, there is an issue where it scrolls all the way to the 0th index when loading past chat history. So, I rotated the ScrollView and added a Spacer to position the chat messages starting from the top.
However, there is a problem.
When a new chat message is added, it automatically scrolls to the bottom. I need it to not scroll automatically if the user is reading a message in the middle.
Does anyone know how to achieve this? Here is my code.
Do you know how to programmatically enable or disable scrolling when using a ScrollView?
struct ChatView: View {
    @State private var items: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue, .yellow, .orange]
    @State private var scrollViewHeight: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var isScrolledToBottom: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView {

                        Spacer()
                            .frame(height: scrollViewHeight - contentHeight)
                    

                    LazyVStack(spacing: 10) {
                        
                            ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                                Rectangle()
                                    .frame(height: 50)
                                    .foregroundStyle(items[index])
                                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
                                    .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center)
                            }
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
                            .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center)
                    }
                    .overlay(
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            Color.clear.preference(key: ContentHeightKey.self, value: geometry.size.height)
                        }
                    )
                    .onPreferenceChange(ContentHeightKey.self) { height in
                        print("ContentHeight: \(height)")
                        contentHeight = height
                    }
                    
                }
                .onChange(of: items) { _ in
                    
                }
                .overlay(
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self, value: geometry.size.height)
                    }
                    .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { height in
                        print("scrollViewHeight: \(height)")
                        scrollViewHeight = height
                    }
                )
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(180))
                .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1, anchor: .center)

                .onAppear {
                    proxy.scrollTo(items.last, anchor: .bottom)
                }
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)) { _ in
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(items.last, anchor: .bottom)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    items.insert(.black, at: 0)
                }, label: {
                    Text("addItem")
                })
                
                Button(action: {
                    items.append(contentsOf: Array(repeating: .red, count: 5))
                }, label: {
                    Text("LoadPreView")
                })
                
            }
        }
    }
}

